# How do I put a button on the third image?

Tags: ios, storyboard

So I am trying to make it so that when you launch the app you get a sliding menu, consisting of 3-4 slides that introduce the app. I have everything set except I don't know how to make it so that when you are on the last image, a button is there to bring you to another view. What should I do?

Each rectangle is an image, but it does not let me put a button in the greyspace:

[image]

Comment: Switch the view controller's size to "freeform". Now you can "grow" the view controller's view until it embraces the whole scroll view and you can add your button on top of the last view image view.

Comment: By the way a UIPageViewController would be a much simpler way to do this (of course that assessment depends on what you think is "simple").

Comment: Check this https://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/